# Font.createFont not working

Tags: java, fonts, awt

When I try to set a JLabel's font by a font that is returned from Font.createFont, JLabel displays nothing:

```
Font tempFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Path to a ttf font"));
Font font =  tempFont.deriveFont(48);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel text = new JLabel("Salam Jahan!");
text.setFont(font);
frame.getContentPane().add(text);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`deriveFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont-int-) specifys the font style rather than the size so the loaded font retains its default size of `0`

```
Font font = tempFont.deriveFont(48);
```

You want the overloaded version of the method

```
Font font = tempFont.deriveFont(48f);
                                  ^
```